# Writing: Self made logical issue with time travel in a story

Tags: fiction, time-depiction, internal-logic

So, I have not gotten anything published yet, but I have had plans for future novels including the one I am most way done with at the moment. As for the Details: It's going to be a multiverse existing where an older world used to be. There are higher beings that were once mortal before taking a specific substance into themselves and now they are indirectly existing across all the realities making up the fundamental parts of each world, as long as each part falls within their 'domain' as it were. (with one exception, but that's another thing entirely)

The reason I describe this is that I was going to establish that any universe their direct conscious selves inhabited could have no alternate versions of itself, as there could only be one of each of these beings. No alternate timelines, no alternate realities.

So, the issue is that at one point I decided that one of them would have a child who eventually tries to go back in time in the world in which their parent lives. They were supposed to leave an artifact in the past that helps the people living there in a variety of ways leading up to when they are born. With help from a mortal friend of theirs.

Originally I thought that maybe there could be a sub-realm to help sort out issues, or that the parent being would bring the ideas of the individuals into the present of the past if they accepted them. Though I am not certain how to solve that quandary, especially since the child would also be one of those beings albeit a new and fresh one while the parent would be in the present future. Suggestions would be appreciated?

Comment: Hi ForrestEM, and welcome. I'm having trouble figuring out what you're really asking here. Are you asking how to handle time travel paradoxes in your story?

Comment: I was just trying to figure out how to handle this one paradox, yes.

Comment: More clarity, please - does the child time-travel back before the old world was split into a multiverse? Did "higher beings" inhabit multiverse as "normal beings" for a while, before becoming "multi" themselves?

Comment: No, just within that specific reality. Also the beings in question were alive in the old world, and became what they were before the world ended (and are the reason there can be multiple realities now). So yes, they were normal before.

Comment: I don't see any plot-affecting paradoxes so far, the "multiverse" part doesn't seem to make any difference. Child travels back to a point in time to when his parent is already "super", his actions are focused on "mortals" and not necessarily affecting the parent or his own birth.

Comment: The issue as I saw it was the emphasis on there being no alternatives to a reality where their main consciousness resided since there could not be more than one. If she was going back in time, then he could not be in the past present and the future present so the reality cannot have two versions..

Comment: So, (time) travel between universes is a small deal in your world, but individual universes' timelines are supposed to be immutable?

Comment: Hi @ForrestEM , this sounds like a worldbuilding question, not a writing question. You are asking about the rules of your "magic" system, not how this effects your story narratively.

Comment: I figured it would be a writing issue if the rules of an entity that defined numerous realities meant that there could only be one of each individual and travel of time in said world would mean that there was another version, but alas. If you do not feel it is as conflicting as I thought it was, then maybe I am overthinking it.

Comment: I must admit, this question left me thoroughly confused as I don't fully understand what's being asked. When you say, "any universe their direct conscious selves inhabited could have no alternate versions of itself", do you mean no alternate versions of the universe, or no alternate version of the being in that universe?

Comment: Get rid of the child?

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand what you're saying: the rule that 'any universe their direct conscious selves inhabited could have no alternate versions of itself' could/would be violated if 'one of them would have a child who eventually tries to go back in time in the world in which their parent lives' and then remains there past the point at which they are conceived or born.

If this is indeed a firm rule that cannot be broken then you have several options, some of which are:

- One of the versions cease to exist at the time of birth. Logically this would have to be the version that went back in time because if the baby ceased to exist then both version would be gone
- There is a destructive event at point of conception/birth, similar to that which a meeting of matter/antimatter would engender
- The alternate version would be instantly and automatically sucked back to their own timeline at point of conception/birth.

There are probably other possibilities, but these seem to me to be that main ones.

Good luck with this and future novels.